# pictures not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I made a code with `multiprocessing` and it does not work. Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk , Image
import multiprocessing

root = Tk()
    
def imgs(img):
    img1 =  "C:/Users/ASUS/pixel/"+img+".png"
    global img2
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img1))
    l = Label(image = img2)
    l.pack()

    q1 = input("what is your favorite color?")
    print("wow " + q1 + " , also is mine's!")

    imgs("f_i")
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=imgs)
    p.start()
#more prints , inputs , etc
```

An image was supposed to show up but it does not. How can I fix that?

Comment: So it looks like your path is C:/Users/ASUS/pixel/f_i.png correct? And you verify this is the exact path of the image you are wanting to show I assume. So do you receive an error code or at run time do you just see a blank space where the image should be?

Comment: Your posted code should not work.  Calling `imgs(...)` inside `imgs()` function will cause recursion error.  Also no argument is passed to target function `imgs()` when creating `Process` but `imgs()` expects one.  Also calling console `input` in a GUI application should be avoided.

Comment: the image shows up , only after the code ends

Comment: @acw1668 makes a good point, `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=imgs)` is not giving the argument required. the recursion should be fixed as well, but you may still get an image if you give imgs the args it expects. You should however take the advice @acw1668 gave and fix the code all together.