# TypeError: 'PhotoImage' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library

i haven't be able to run this code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk , Image
from multiprocessing import *

root = Tk()

def imgs(img):
    img1 =  "C:/Users/ASUS/pixel/"+img+".png"
    global img2
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img1))
    l = Label(root, image = img2)
    l.pack()
# prints , inputs , etc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imgs("m_man")
    p = Process(args = (img2), target = imgs)
    p.start()
# more prints , etc
```

i have been receving this error:`TypeError: 'PhotoImage' object is not iterable` and i diden't understand what does the error means , what can i do to fix the code , and could someone explain what does the error mean

Comment: Read up on [How to start a separate new Tk() window using multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55179195/7414759)

Comment: Why don't you just update your question in [pictures-not-showing-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768445/pictures-not-showing-up) instead of creating one?

Answer (score 0):

Argument `args` of `Process` expects an iterable object, like list or tuple, but you pass it a single item, which cannot be iterated. You wanted to pass a tuple, but parenthesis in python do not make a tuple, a comma does. The `(img2)` is not a tuple, it's just a single item in parenthesis. The `(img2,)` is a tuple with a single element `img2`. So you need to call it like this:

```
p = Process(args = (img2,), target = imgs)
```

Comment: `imgs(...)` has been called before that line, so `img2` will be created.  But other issue is that `imgs()` expects a string argument, not `PhotoImage`.